# Cloth Vertex Groups Problems in Animation

Tags: animation, vertex-groups

I am currently animating my character. I set the parent of the cape to the neck bone and assigned vertex groups in the cloth modifier. However, when I animate it, there seems to have something under the cape. Even if I remove everything that is supposed to be under the cape, it still looks like the situation in the photo below. Please tell me how to solve this.

Link to file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CL1vz-TE52nkvyK6aDs268PHjIFtQ96R?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just move your collision modifier after the armature modifier:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: @Vic if he answered correctly, check the validation button  ;)